# What information should I preemptively store to be able to recover encrypted data?

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs, luks

All of the posts that I can find regarding encrypted-data recovery regard specific situations. I currently have functioning partitions and directories, but would like to maximise my chances of recovering data should something go wrong (in addition to my back ups). What information (such as keys, passphrases, configuration etc.) should I keep in cold storage given the following setup?

Ubuntu root is installed on a LUKS-encrypted drive. I have a second HDD that is also LUKS-encrypted and is set up to automatically mount upon login. Additionally my home directory is mounted with ecryptfs.

I know that for ecryptfs I should be storing the output of ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase, but what should be done for each of the LUKS partitions? I vaguely remember that there is some other passphrase that should be stored in case particular partition header information is corrupted.

Thanks for your help. As an aside, should anyone be interested in the cold storage, I plan to simply create level H (high error correction) QR codes for printing to paper along with the actual data as text.

Comment: most any back up strategy will work, just encrypt your backup.archive

Comment: I mean beyond an external backup. What is required for me to be able to decrypt the partition?

Comment: Your data is decrypted when you log in. I would use the back up strategy of choice and encrypt you back up with an alternate technology. Backing up your data while it is still encrypted is asking for problems.

Comment: I think I'm wording the question incorrectly. Ignore the separate backup. In the event that I have a hardware malfunction and need to plug my disk into another computer, what information will I need to access the contents?

Comment: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in the original question, what should be done for LUKS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LUKS, the only data that is critical for decryption is the LUKS header. The header can be backed up to a file with `cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup` and restored with `cryptsetup luksHeaderRestore`. See `man cryptsetup`:

> ```
> luksHeaderBackup <device> --header-backup-file <file>
> ```
>
> Stores a binary backup of the LUKS header and keyslot area.
>
> Note: Using '-' as filename writes the header backup to a file named '-'.
>
> WARNING:  This  backup  file and a passphrase valid at the time of backup allows decryption of the LUKS data area,
>                 even if the passphrase was later changed or removed from the LUKS device. Also note that with a header backup  you
>                 lose the ability to securely wipe the LUKS device by just overwriting the header and key-slots. You either need to
>                 securely erase all header backups in addition or overwrite the encrypted data area as well.  The second option  is
>                 less secure, as some sectors can survive, e.g. due to defect management.
>
> ```
> luksHeaderRestore <device> --header-backup-file <file>
> ```
>
> Restores a binary backup of the LUKS header and keyslot area from the specified file.
>
> Note: Using '-' as filename reads the header backup from a file named '-'.
>
> WARNING: Header and keyslots will be replaced, only the passphrases from the backup will work afterwards.
>
> This command requires that the master key size and data offset of the LUKS header already on the device and of the
>                 header backup match. Alternatively, if there is no LUKS header on the device, the backup will also be  written  to
>                 it.

Answer (score 2):

Run  ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase  at the terminal screen and write down the output for disaster recovery.

1. type    ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase  in the terminal screen
2. it will prompted you with "Passphrase:", it wants your user login password
3. The output will look like this example "1b6acbada5e3a61ebe324a4745e61ba8"
    the 32 character output is your "passphrase" you need to write down and store
    in a safe place.

To recover your data in the future follow this guide..

http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/