# Construct a LUKS partition with specified start/end sectors to recover the old one

Tags: luks

I have an external HDD with three main partitions, Vol2 of which is a LUKS partition. I compromised the disk by installing a boot image. `man cryptsetup` says:

> LUKS header: If the header of a LUKS volume gets damaged, all data is
> permanently lost unless you have a header-backup.

therefore, can I theoretically recover Vol2? Here's what I get using testdisk/GIT analysis:

```
[ ... ]
P Linux filesys. data 1134254080 1134258175 4096
LUKS 1 (Data size unknown), 2097 KB / 2048 KiB
[ ... ]
```

Would it make sense to "construct a partition with starting sector 1134254080 and spanning the rest of the disk=." (I'm quoting from another forum)? If applicable, how to go about it (step by step)?

Comment: It makes no sense at all. No backups means *all data is permanently lost*.

Comment: @ChanganAuto but maybe the LUKS  header is not damaged.

Comment: It is, it always is in that scenario. Recover form your backups and move on. If you don't have backups then lesson learned, one hopes.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm quite resigned as is. How would I backup the header for next time?

Comment: @Erwann How to backup and restore the header is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/646246/1115551).

Comment: Think about having an up-to-that backup of the contents, i.e., personal files. That's what matters at the end of the day. File systems, partitions, LUKS or any other encryption type, all of this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Sheldon yes, I remember the LUKS encryuption passphrase if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The kick in the ass is the external hdd was the backup.

Comment: @Erwann I meant the actual key, something like a 32 bytes raw/binary AES key. Sounds like you don't have that, but it was worth a shot.